# Write/Read object to file

Tags: java, class, object, filewriter

I'm trying to read/write an object to a file, and came up with this code, which I have edited, but when I open the file it appears weird characters and signs, I guess thats the Serializable stuff in there. Is there any way to write it properly?
That is my code so far.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;


public class Controlador_Dades_Doctor 
{
    public void escriureFitxer(Doctor doctor){

        ObjectOutputStream out;
        try {
            File file = new File("Doctors.ser");
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            out.writeObject(doctor);

            out.flush();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Object written to file");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error with specified file") ;
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error with I/O processes") ;
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }             
    }
}
```

Thats my output file, as you can see it has strange characters.

```
¬í sr DoctorÑmçUÝâ& I idI num_guardiesD souL nomt Ljava/lang/String;xp      @—p     t rux
```

Also, I've got another class which is a Map of this first class, I've got no clue how I could write them to a file aswell, so a file would contain my Doctor Map.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "write it properly"? What do you expect? Why?

Comment: The point of serialization is to write out the content of the object so that it can be loaded back into java object form later. The native Java serialization you're using has a specific format of how it seralizes an object. If you want a more intuitive and readable form of serialization you should look to JSON or some other serailzation method.

Comment: I guess I meant buffering writting/reading instead then, I've solved it, and now its working properly.

Answer (score 2):

"Write it properly".  This is what Serialize is supposed to do.  There is nothing wrong with what it is doing.  If you want to read that same object you deserialize the file and recreate the object.  If you want human readable file with objects data then you should create your own method for writing the object data to a .txt file and format it how you want.